# Correct way of importing a class into a testfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to write some unit test for a Python project. The way I am importing the class into the testfile seems wrong to me or at least not the most efficient way of doing it.

My folder structure is:

[image]

The way I am importing `ClassA` into `test_ClassA` is:

```
import pytest
import sys

sys.path.append(r'C:\python-projects\pytestmethodoverridetest')

from src.ClassA import ClassA

def testtest():
    # arrange
    sut = ClassA()
    expected = 5
    # act
    actual = sut.party(4)
    # assert
    assert expected == actual
```

Is there a way for me to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it relative to your file's location:

```
sys.path.append( os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/..'))
```